# AIX 7.1 failed disk, need to figure out what physical disk this is?

Tags: local-storage, aix, disk

I have an AIX 7.1 p650 box that has a disk array attached directly to it, on the array I have a failed disk..

```
PV_NAME           PV STATE          TOTAL PPs   FREE PPs    FREE DISTRIBUTION
hdisk0            missing           273         0           00..00..00..00..00

ERRPT INFO:
LABEL:          DISK_ERR4
IDENTIFIER:     49A83216

Date/Time:       Mon Jun 24 13:33:34 PDT 2013
Sequence Number: 3503
Machine Id:      00001501D600
Node Id:         van-oppy
Class:           H
Type:            TEMP
WPAR:            Global
Resource Name:   hdisk0
Resource Class:  disk
Resource Type:   scsd
Location:        U787B.001.DNWD723-P1-C3-T1-L1-L0
```

I think there is a way through SMITTY to turn on a light indicator on the array to be able to locate the failed disk, but I am not sure?

Anyone out there able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `diag`.

```
$ diag 
<enter> 
Task Selection 
Hot Plug Task 
SCSI Hot Swap Manager 
Identify a Device Attached to a SCSI Hot Swap Enclosure Device
```

It should blink the LED of the device you requested.

Comment: Hi Corey, that worked.. i spent a few hours Googling after I posted on stack and found the same answer.. though, thank you for answering.